# How to commit a project file inside a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, tortoisegit

More or less, I have managed to have a main Git and a submodule with this doc: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

But how to version a main project file located in the submodule (for example the submodule setups)?

Here is my tree of directories:

- main project

  - dir1
  - dir2
  - *submodule*

    - *core*
    - **setups** ← This file belongs to the main project

Note: I'm using gitwin and tortoisegit.

Comment: couldn´t `setups` be child of `main project` if it belongs to it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Repos "own" everything that hangs from its main directory. What you are mentioning would involve checking in submodule/setups/file as part of the main directory, which would be impeded by the fact that there's a `.git` in `submodule`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will move my sub-file somewhere else